# NGiNX + PHP5-fpm + CDN Tools (plugin)

Tags: nginx, wordpress, cdn, rackspace-cloud

I am trying to activate the CDN tools plugin and I keep getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 30720 bytes) in /srv/www/www.triathleteskitchen.com/wp-content/plugins/cdn-tools/cdn_classes/cloudfiles/cloudfiles_http.php on line 252
```

After extensive research on this issue in which I updated both of the following settings:

```
max_execution_time = 300
memory_limit = 128M
```

and verified the settings are active by setting up a dump phpinfo() page.  Still no luck /cry

I am curious if any php geeks better than me have any ideas or can point me in the right direction.

Happy Holidays to you and your families :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way I was able to fix this issue was, deactivate all other plugins, than setup the CDN plug in, than activate the other plugins.  seems odd, but if anyone has a better idea, please let me know.  thank you